# FadeIn content from database with grabbed by some php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, fadein

This piece of code (with another php file) grabs some content from a database and pus it into a div called about_content.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('a#about-menu').click(function() {
            var id = $('a#about-menu').attr('class');

            $.post('subpages/content_about/about_content.php',{id: id}, function(id){

                $('div#about_content').text(id)
            });
        });
});
```

Everything works, but can you tell me how I can modify this so the stuff fades in, instead of just being smacked right in... I'm not sure how to use the fadeIn function in this scenario..

Comment: You better start to accept some answers, 10 questions and no answers accepted...

Answer (score 1):

Try..

```
$('div#about_content').css('opacity', '0').text(id).fadeIn();
```

Comment: Oh and also, it would be cool if we could avoid the text function, cause I just realised i need to smack in some text which could hold html formatting...

Comment: so change `text(id)` to `html(id)`

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
   $('div#about_content').hide();
   $('div#about_content').html(id);
   $('div#about_content').fadeIn(1000);
```

didnt test it, so im not sure you could try

Answer (score 0):

This fades out the existing content then replaces the content and fade it in!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a#about-menu').click(function() {
        var id = $('a#about-menu').attr('class');
        $.post('subpages/content_about/about_content.php',{id: id}, function(id){
            $('div#about_content').fadeOut('fast',function(){ $(this).html(id).fadeIn(); });
        });
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Mvwj9/)